# Errors on strictNullChecks

Tags: angular

I have enabled the strictNullChecks in the compiler options. Now I get errors in parts of the code accordingly. Some of them I get fixed, others I'm a bit stuck on. There the solution is probably too simple.
Error message first:
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'User'.

Code example:

```
export class XComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User = null;

  ngOnit() {}

  newUser(): void {
    this.user = null;
  }
}

export class User{
public name: string;
}
```

I would have solved this now like this:

```
this.user = new User();
```

Is this the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could explicitly allow `null` there:

```
  user: User | null = null;
```

Comment: But does this make so much sense?

Comment: Sure: the value is supposed to be of type `User`, but you allow it also to be null, and make it explicit in the variable declaration. That's more or less what `strictNullChecks` are for: no nulls slipping below the radar.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. What I'm actually questioning is whether it makes sense to assign the value null to the user at all. Or if undefined would not be the better choice at this point?